# Unit testing a Powershell Azure Function App?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function written in Powershell:

```
function Invoke {
    param($Request)
    Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
        StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
        Body       = "Hello!"
    })
}
```

I have a Pester unit test for this function:

```
Describe "Invoke" {
    It "Returns a 200 response" {
        $Response = Invoke -Request [HttpRequestContext]@{}
        $Response.StatusCode | Should Be ([HttpStatusCode]::OK)
    }
}
```

Running this test yields:

```
Describing Invoke
  [-] Returns a 200 response 4ms (3ms|1ms)
   RuntimeException: Unable to find type [HttpRequestContext].
```

Presumably the PowerShellWorker injects these types when it runs the script and so they are not available when Pester invokes the test. In falling order of desirability, how can I:

1. Import these types in my test run? For example, is there a module I could import?
2. Inject mocks of these types? Pester has support for creating mocks of objects, but not inject types?
3. Ask the PowerShellWorker to invoke the function from my test? (I could probably invoke `func host start` and write integration tests instead, but I would really prefer to have unit tests if possible.)

I'd appreciate any lead that can help me with this.

UPDATE: As pointed out in comments, I had deleted a `param()` when compacting my example. To clarify, the idea is to support type annotations in both test and production code.

UPDATE2: Corrected spelling as per mclayton's suggestion.

Comment: A response is always sent on the same connection as the request.  So A test method must first get a request.  For testing the best way is send a request with special messages that your test method parses and then send a response back based on the special messages.  The server is only a dumb app that does what is in the client request.

Comment: @jdweng Perhaps you are referring to the fact that I send `-Request` but have no matching `param()` entry in `Invoke`? Sorry about that; I was just trying to minimize the number of moving parts. I'll update the question. However, this is irrelevant to the question, which is about trying to support type annotations in both test and production code. As you can see from the error message, the error occurs before we get to invoking `Invoke`.

Comment: I'm talking about testing.  During Testing you want the server to send something different than normal processing.  So you want code in the server to send known responses to client to test the client response code.

Comment: Is the typo ```Invoke -Request [HttpRequstContext]@{}``` (missing ```e``` after ```u``` in ```[HttpRequestContext]```) in your original code, or is that a transcribing error in your question?

Comment: @mclayton Oops. That's a spelling issue in the example tho. The error message is pasted from my actual test code where `HttpRequestContext` is correctly spelled.

Comment: You might have found these links already (and I’ve not actually tried it myself, so they may not be of any practical use anyway) but I’ll post them in case they help… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Cpowershell%2Cportal%2Cbash seems to suggest how to install a local version of the Powershell Functions runtime, and https://gist.github.com/TylerLeonhardt/bca6e0991fd12889fce0ebc420e64667 suggests you can abuse it to load the runtime assemblies *in-process* for *unit* testing purposes as opposed to *integration* testing. HTH…

Comment: @mclayton Will you look at that; this [ugly stuff](https://gist.github.com/TylerLeonhardt/bca6e0991fd12889fce0ebc420e64667#file-azfuncenvironment-psm1-L62-L66) is exactly what I was expecting to find. It seems to be working, too. It will not solve all problems, because e.g. `HttpRequestContext.Query` is readonly, but `New-MockObject` can help with that, now that the type is known. I'll accept this if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Bittrance - might be better if you want to answer your own question as you've got a working example in front of you that you can post - I'd just be cutting and pasting my comments which were speculative at best :-).

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a really concise approach to unit testing PowerShell Azure Functions....or at least they certainly get less love than C#/Javascript/Python in general.

You can however mock the type in pester using [New-MockObject](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/New%E2%80%90MockObject)

I've also seen ways of using entryPoints to run a script and then test the script independently of your Azure Function so you don't have to rely on the worker runtime at all but how deep down the rabbit hole do you want to go?!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because the type you are trying to mock is unknown. As far as I can tell, the type argument is passed directly to [GetUninitializedObject](https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/08a1e0057bd0088f939ecce3bc60d9e0a237c8be/src/functions/New-MockObject.ps1#L94) and so Powershell needs to know the real type to create the mock? `New-MockObject -Type "HttpRequestContext"` results in "PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "HttpRequestContext" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type""

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this today, and I solved it by moving the `using` statement in `run.ps1` to the top of the `profile.ps1` file, and adding a mock type to the unit tests in the `BeforeEach`, before dot-sourcing `run.ps1`:

```
enum HttpStatusCode {
    OK
    InternalServerError
}
class HttpResponseContext {
    [HttpStatusCode]$StatusCode
    [string]$ContentType
    [string]$Body
}
function Push-OutputBinding($Name, $Value) {}
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: You could probably even put that into a separate file (something like MockAzFunctionTypes.ps1) and dot-source that in tests across multiple files.

Comment: Oops, I just realized when I pushed to production that the using statement in profile.ps1 does not work, it will blow up at runtime (in Azure) when you don't include it. I thought it was OK since I could run it with the Azure Function Core tools just fine.